# Hello how to fix this E/mple.profitfis: open libmigui.so failed! dlopen - dlopen failed: library "libmigui.so" not found

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

helo, so I'm trying to run the application that I made, when I run it on my smartphone (psyhcal device) during the build I get an error like this E/mple.profitfis: open libmigui.so failed! dlopen - dlopen failed: library "libmigui.so" not found .the application is installed but it doesn't display the textview and also when I use the virtual device there is no error and the textview is there

is there any way to fix it?